# Can I filter my flagging history?

Tags: support, flags

I checked my flagging history today and noticed in the summary on the right that I apparently have five flags awaiting review. Curious, I started looking to see what they were, but with over 2000 flags to my name it's going to take a lot of patience to find the active ones. Is there any way to filter my flagging history to identify active flags (or declined, disputed, etc.)?

Comment: related: [Flag history page needs better design](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197420/flag-history-page-needs-better-design), [Flagging summary improvement : filters](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92484/flagging-summary-improvement-filters)

Comment: I haven't tried it, but maybe it's possible to write a [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) for it

Comment: @Serpiton thanks for the suggestion - I've not used the Data Explorer. That's going to take more time than I have at present. Maybe I'll revisit this is a few days.

Comment: @chuex Thanks for the links - particularly the second one. It seems this has already been covered and an attempt to re-awaken it in April has fallen on deaf ears. For five active flags it hardly seems worth the effort.

Comment: I believe flag expiration means you can't (or generally won't) have active flags older than a certain age.

Comment: @user2357112 Well, I checked page 49 of my filter list (the last page) which contains items date June 19 2013. I'm sure there should be flags before that so maybe you're right. However, I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17410358/1864610) lurking there with an active flag that should have been closed in minutes, but has somehow survived. That accounts for one, and another dates from a couple of days ago so only three to find now...

Comment: @user0000000 that will make sense, still checking the avaliable tables I've found the `PendingFlags` table and some `ReviewTasks...` tables, but I haven't run any query to verify how to use the data of those tables.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is available since October, 2015 [Categorized views in past flags (helpful/declined/disputed)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171720/158100).

You can click on any of the categories to filter your flags:

[image: flag filters]