# How can I find my disputed and declined flags?

Tags: support, declined-flags, disputed-flags, flag-history

I'm curious to find out what my declined and disputed flags were.

What's the best way to find these?   (My flags go over more than one page, so it's not attractive to manually go hunting).

Comment: Thanks - I upvoted that request.   I think your comment could be the actual answer?

Comment: After reading @RetoKoradi comments below, it seems like http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119764/how-do-i-see-which-comment-flags-have-been-declined is a bit different from what you have asked for. In which case you may post a new feature-request for it.

Comment: You could also add the flags that are in the "waiting for review" state to your request, if it makes sense to you. The solution I picture would add live links to the statistics on the right side of the flag list. So when it for example shows "8 disputed", that would be a link, and the list in the main pane would be filtered to show just those 8 flags if I click on the link.

Comment: This is not a dupe of the linked question.   The accepted answer to that questions shows us where to find our flag list.  I already know that.   As I clearly state in the question: I'm asking about dealing with the fact that the flag list pointed to in that answer goes over more than one page.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently you cannot view that information easily without going through pages and pages of your flagging history.

Comment: (I didn't upvote this because I don't like what it says, but I accept that it is the  answer :D :D )

Comment: @GreenAsJade its completely your prerogative :) you may vote however you like ... but hey it is a support question :)

Comment: (I'm somewhat alluding to another question/thread going on at the moment about what is the meaning of upvote and downvote on meta.   Does it mean the answer is good or that I agree with it? ;) )

Comment: Now with the context of the other post, your first comment makes sense :)

Comment: That MSE request sounds different to me. I believe it was about **comment** flags not being shown anywhere. The way I understand the OP's request, this is about a simple method to filter out the disputed/declined flags in the list of all flags that is already shown. Which I would like to see as well.

Comment: @RetoKoradi valid point. I have removed the link and added a comment for OP

Comment: Hang on.  I just went through all my flags, and couldn't find any indication of disputed.   How do I identify disputed flags?

Comment: @GreenAsJade In the flagging history. For example: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gSMaW.png

Comment: @GreenAsJade if you don't like how things are done now, consider taking a look at [Can I filter my flagging history?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261919/839601) and [Flag summary sort by active disputed helpful declined etc](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254784/839601)